# Navigation bar not showing over TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I can't explain why this code is not working. For some reason the navigation bar is translucent and the contents of the tableView are scrolling over it.

here is the code of the Button

```
 let outlineViewController = OutlineTableviewController()
        outlineViewController.pdfOutlineRoot = pdfoutline
        outlineViewController.delegate = self

        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: outlineViewController)
        self.present(nav, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

here is the code of the tableView

```
super.viewDidLoad()

    let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(dismissView))

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newBackButton

    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.51, blue:0.78, alpha:1.0)


   self.tableView.dataSource = self
   self.tableView.delegate = self

   tableView?.register(UINib(nibName: "OutlineTableViewCell", bundle: nil),
                        forCellReuseIdentifier: "OutlineTableViewCell")
}
```

and here is the result:
the background color is not showing and the table goes under the navigationbar.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine. I think the problem is in another place. Did you set navigation bar background anywhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you trungduc for your reply.

after spending hours trying to figure out what the problem was, I finally was able to fix this issue by changing the color in the root view.

```
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: oulineViewController)
        nav.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.51, blue:0.78, alpha:1.0)
        self.present(nav, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the magic word in your question: "translucent."

I had the same problem: the navigation bar was showing on the root view in Storyboard, but when running the Simulator - there was no navigation bar at the top of the views. This solved it:

Navigation Controller > Navigation Bar > UNCHECK Translucent (it is checked by default). This did two things:

1. My Navigation Bar shows on all subsequent views.
2. The topmost subview (a tableview in your case) is now at Y=0, and not Y=64.

[image]